# How to extend a custom element ("vanilla" web-component, no Polymer)

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I have a custom element, called `x-foo`. I would like to extend it, and create a `x-bar` element:

```
xBar = document.registerElement("x-bar", {
    prototype: xBarProto,
    extends: "x-foo"
});
```

But it doesn't work. It's not possible to extend custom elements this way. Chrome issues this error:

> Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on
>   'Document': Registration failed for type 'x-foo-extended'. The tag
>   name specified in 'extends' is a custom element name. **Use inheritance
>   instead**.

Use inheritance instead? Ok, how exactly? **Any examples?**

Note: I'm not using Polymer. Just plain vanilla web-components in Chrome, with no polyfills.

Comment: where does `xBarProto` came from?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Custom Element Inheritance</h1>
 <nav>
  <button onclick="addFoo()">Add Foo</button>
  <button onclick="addBar()">Add Bar</button>
 </nav>
 <script>

  //x-foo
  var xFooProto = Object.create( HTMLDivElement.prototype )
  xFooProto.createdCallback = function ()
  {
   this.innerHTML = "XFoo Custom Element"
  }
  var xFoo = document.registerElement( "x-foo", { prototype: xFooProto, extends: "div" } )

  function addFoo()
  {
   console.log( "addFoo()" )
   var xf = new xFoo
   document.body.appendChild( xf )
  }

  //x-bar
  xBarProto = Object.create( xFooProto )
  xBarProto.attachedCallback = function ()
  {
   this.innerHTML = "XBar Custom Element inherits from " + this.innerHTML
  }
  var xBar = document.registerElement( "x-bar", { prototype: xBarProto, extends: "div" } )

  function addBar()
  {
   console.log( "addBar()" )
   var xb = new xBar
   document.body.appendChild( xb )
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can only extend a restricted subset of standard HTML Elements, not Custom Elements.
You'll have to :

1) Get the `x-foo` prototype (`xFooProto` I guess).

2) Inherit from it:

```
var xBarProto = Object.create( xFooProto )
```

3) Augment it with its specific methods and properties.

4) Register it as an extension of the original `x-foo` base element:

```
document.registerElement( "x-bar", { prototype: xBarProto, extends: "div" } )
```

Comment: This seems quite limiting. HTML rocks managed to do it but now we get this error in chrome. What is going on.